# Cannot get react-hook-form to validate an email properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js, react-hook-form

I have spent ages trying to get this to validate properly but it just isn't happening. Ive added some text at the bottom to output when an error occurs regarding the `email` however it always says `no error`, no matter what.

Edit:
Sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-star-8gv3l

Here is my input:

```
           <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="email"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Email address
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <input
                  {...register("email", {
                    required: {
                      value: true,
                      message: "Please enter your email address",
                    },
                    pattern: {
                      value:
                        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                      message: "Invalid email address",
                    },
                  })}
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  autoComplete="off"
                  className={`input w-full ${
                    !errors.email && dirtyFields.email && "!bg-green-50"
                  }`}
                />
              </div>
              {errors.email ? "error" : "no error"}
              {errors.email?.message && (
                <ErrorMessage>{errors.email?.message}</ErrorMessage>
              )}
            </div>
```

Here is my hook:

```
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    control,
    formState: { errors, isValid, dirtyFields },
  } = useForm<SignupProps>({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      username: "",
      firstName: "",
      surname: "",
      isShop: false,
    },
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox please ? It's easier to help you

Comment: Sure thing! one moment @Joris

Comment: @Joris link added! thank you

Comment: The main issue I see here is that there is no form, and no way to submit the form.

Comment: @JakeWorth in my actual file I have a form and a way to submit, Im just struggling with the inputs and their validations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According your codesandbox, here is what you've to change:

- Add `<form />` tag
- Add `mode: 'onChange'` in `useForm` options to display the error while typing in the input
- Add a submit button if you want to trigger validation on submit
- Display error message passed in validation

Working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-sea-ps37x?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: It was the `mode` that fixed it, thank you!

Comment: for me it was adding `<form />` tag,  email validation with `@` is handled

Comment: I used useForm<Inputs>({ mode: "all" }) to make sure I capture all possible types. Thanks for the info Joris!